# How to use php read ppt on the web

Tags: php, powerpoint

I have a simple question, the question is how could i upload a ppt file and display the ppt on the web. I have try to google the question, and i have read a page is use google doc and use the url to read my ppt file url link. So, the question is not to achieve? Thanks!

Comment: I'd give up and go the Google Docs route. This'd take massive amounts of code and time to build yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Google search of "PHP ppt" yields [this](http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/). *Edit:* But it only supports `.pptx`.

Comment: Unfortunately, PHPPowerPoint can only write pptx at present, it cannot read ppt or pptx files

Comment: @MarkBaker Hm. So it does. Disregard, then.

Comment: So, I can only use google docs route, The problem is a large projects...thanks.

Comment: If you _really_ wanted to, you could take the time and understand the format of `.ppt` and `.pptx` files, and build a converter yourself.

Comment: ok, thanks, i think, i use google docs router now, and if i can, i will research the format.